# NestJS With supertest doesn't compile with 'Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature'

Tags: typescript, nestjs

When trying to run e2e tests from the NestJS examples, my test does not compile with 'Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature' for the line

```
request(app.getHttpServer())
```

Code is from the NestJS testing examples.

It might have to do with my tsconfig?

```
import * as request from "supertest";
import { Test } from "@nestjs/testing";
import { INestApplication } from "@nestjs/common";

describe("App", () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: []
    }).compile();

    app = module.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  it(`/GET`, () => {
    return request(app.getHttpServer())
      .get("/")
      .expect(200);
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });
});
```

Comment: This fixed it: import request from "supertest";

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This fixed it

```
import request from "supertest";
```

Answer (score 0):

You must import the module.

```
import * as request from "supertest";
import { Test } from "@nestjs/testing";
import { INestApplication } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AppModule } from '../src/app.module';

describe("App", () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule] // <- this
    }).compile();

    app = module.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  it(`/GET`, () => {
    return request(app.getHttpServer())
      .get("/")
      .expect(200);
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });
});
```